# How to hide image and show it upon hover on a different element

Tags: jquery

Struggled with this for a while and couldn't find a previous solution on here. I imagine it's something very basic that I'm missing. Would be grateful for any assistance.

I'm attempting to hide the image and then show it when a link is hovered over.

However the image is not hiding upon document load. I tried other ways of achieving this, such as hiding it by default (opacity:0;) and then creating ".show" in css and telling the jQuery to addClass show. This didn't work either and I believed that simply hide and show upon hover would be the better solution.

EDIT: Thanks for your responses. Unfortunately this still isn't working, possibly due to a conflict elsewhere in the code. Thanks for your help.

```html
<div id="content">
    <img id=“firstImage” src="image.jpg">
    <p>Here is <a href="#" target="_blank" id="firstLink">The Link</a></p>
</div>
```

```css
#content img {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').hide();
    $('#firstLink').hover(function() { 
        $('#firstImage').show();
        $('#firstImage').hide);
    });
```

Comment: You're calling `.show()` and then immediately hiding it again with `hide()`.  Remove the last line of the hover function.  Not to mention you're missing the parenthesis for `hide()`.

Comment: Note that you're using fancy quotes in your example `id=“firstImage”`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is partly because you call `show()` then immdiately `hide()` the element on hover. Also there is a syntax error as you're missing a parenthesis in your `hide()` call and you're using non-standard quotes around the `id` property value of the `img`.

You can simplify the code to just use `toggle()` under the `hover` event, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').hide();
  $('#firstLink').hover(function() {
      $('#firstImage').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#content img {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <img id="firstImage" src="image.jpg">
  <p>Here is <a href="#" target="_blank" id="firstLink">The Link</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

first make the image hidden from css better than `hide()` it while loading page !!

```
#content img{
display:none;
}
```

then  this  is the correct jquery code :

```
$(function{
$("#firstLink").hover(function(){
$("#firstImage").show();
});
});
```

you have a syntax problem in you code you write `hide)` instead of `hide()` .

and this if it was correct it will hide the element immediately after shown it so you have to delete it .
that all;

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS by rearranging your layout a little. If your `<a>` is before the `<img>` you can use a sibling selector (`+` or `~`) to invoke `:hover` on the target element.

Added a bulky jQuery using the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and `.css` method on the `opacity` property since you have it in CSS and all the common answers of `show()` and `toggle()` have been done already, btw `fadeIn()` is another method with the same results.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('#secondLink').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $("#secondImage").css({
    'opacity': 1,
    'transition': 'all 1s ease-in'
  });
});
$('#secondLink').on('mouseleave', function() {
  3
  $("#secondImage").css({
    'opacity': 0,
    'transition': 'all 1s ease-in'
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 50vw;
}
img {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}
a#firstLink:hover + img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Never use “ or ” in code unless it's pure text. Use " or ' instead-->


<div id="content">
  <span>Here is </span>
  <a href="#/" id="firstLink">The Link</a>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" id='firstImage'>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" id='secondImage'>
  <p>Here is
    <a href="#/" id="secondLink">The Second Link</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Outstanding! That's fantastic. Thank you so much. Didn't realise it was possible without some JS.

Comment: Indeed, sir. If this answer has met and/or exceeded expectations, please click the green **✔**.